# USB key not mounting at boot to unlock LUKS system

Tags: boot, usb, encryption, luks

I am running Debian Jessie. I have 2 hard drives with my various partitions spread across both (not RAID). Both of them are separately LUKS encrypted, and LVMs sit upon both of those. My `/boot` partition is the only partition not included on the two hard drives; instead, it is located on an unencrypted USB stick. On the `/boot` partition is `myKeyfile.key` which should unlock both of the hard drives [but doesn't]. My goal is to have fully inaccessible/useless disks whenever the system boots without the USB stick.

Here is what I have done to accomplish this. I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19713920) on StackOverflow as a guide.

---

### `/etc/default/cryptdisks`

```
# Mountpoints to mount, before cryptsetup is invoked at initscripts. Takes
# mountpoints which are configured in /etc/fstab/ as arguments. Separate
# mountpoints by space.  

# original: CRYPTDISKS_MOUNT=""
CRYPTDISKS_MOUNT=/boot
```

According to the comment, I just have to make sure I have the proper mountpoint name as described in `fstab`. For completeness, here is the relevant line:

### `/etc/fstab`

```
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
 UUID=<usb uuid>    /boot      ext4   defaults    0     2
```

---

### `/etc/crypttab`

```
sda1_crypt  UUID=<disk uuid>  /boot/myKeyfile.key  luks,keyscript=/bin/passphrase-from-usb
sda2_crypt  UUID=<disk uuid>  /boot/myKeyfile.key  luks,keyscript=/bin/passphrase-from-usb
```

I could specify the UUID of the USB drive (instead of `/boot/myKeyfile.key`), but then I'm not sure how I would specify that `myKeyfile.key` is the file I'm interested in.

### `/etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/passphrase-from-usb`

```
#!/bin/sh

PREREQ=""

prereqs() {
        echo "$PREREQ"
}

case "$1" in
        prereqs)
                prereqs
                exit 0
       ;;
esac

. "${CONFDIR}/initramfs.conf"
. /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hook-functions

copy_exec /bin/passphrase-from-usb /bin
```

### `/bin/passphrase-from-usb`

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

    if ! [ -e "$CRYPTTAB_KEY" ]; then
        echo "Waiting for USB stick to be recognized..." >&2
        sleep 5
    fi
    if [ -e "$CRYPTTAB_KEY" ]; then
        echo "Unlocking the disk $CRYPTTAB_SOURCE ($CRYPTTAB_NAME) from USB key" >&2
        echo "Using $CRYPTTAB_KEY as the key source" >&2
        dd if="$CRYPTTAB_KEY" bs=1 count=256 2>/dev/null
        exit
    else
        echo "Can't find $CRYPTTAB_KEY; USB stick not present." >&2
    fi

/lib/cryptsetup/askpass "Manually unlock the disk ($CRYPTTAB_NAME)\nEnter passphrase: "
```

---

---

This is what I am greeted with upon booting:

```
Loading, please wait...
   Volume group "vg-root" not found
   Skipping volume group vg-root
Unable to find LVM volume vg-root/lv-root
   Volume group "vg-other" not found
   Skipping volume group vg-other
Unable to find LVM volume vg-other/lv-swap

Waiting for USB stick to be recognized...
[   3.159979] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] No Caching mode page found
[   3.160152] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through

Can't find /boot/myKeyfile.key; USB stick not present. 

Manually unlock the disk (sda1_crypt)
Enter passphrase:
```

After I enter the passphrase, the same exchange happens for the second disk, `sdb1_crypt`.

---

I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what. Since `CRYPTDISKS_MOUNT` "specifies the mountpoints that are mounted before cryptdisks is invoked", I thought adding `/boot` to it would make `/boot` available before the unlocking procedure began. However, it does not appear to be mounted when `/bin/passphrase-from-usb` runs.

I am sure that `myKeyfile.key` is added as a LUKS key to both drives, and I have updated the `initramfs` via `update-initramfs -u`.

Answer (score 0):

during boot, initramfs doesn't mount /boot. if you want use the file in /boot, you may mount the /boot manually. may add following commands to the script passphrase-from-usb.

```
mkdir -p /tmp-boot
mount <usb uuid> /tmp-boot -t ext4
dd if=/tmp-boot/myKeyfile.key bs=1 count=256 2>/dev/null
umount /tmp-boot
```

Also, this http://wejn.org/how-to-make-passwordless-cryptsetup.html will be very helpful.