# Automatic unlock LVM partitions with a Key LUKS dm-crypt

Tags: lvm, luks

I'm trying to make an automatic unlock of other partitions, I have 9 Logical volumes including root, and I know root `LVM` will unlock manually true password to have a key decrypted.

My goal is unlock with a usbkey. I followed some tutorials but no one did it, so I'm here asking your help, I think the scripts aren't right or I'm doing something wrong or they are out of date.

My system is Debian 8.3 with 9 `LVM`'s all of them `LUKS` encrypted.

I tried with those tutorials:

- [USB key not mounting at boot to unlock LUKS system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237054/usb-key-not-mounting-at-boot-to-unlock-luks-system)
- [How to configure LVM & LUKS to autodecrypt partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59487/how-to-configure-lvm-luks-to-autodecrypt-partition)
- [Unlocking LUKS with USB key - method - seeking help to improve](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=241942)
- [Debian Lenny + LUKS encrypted root + hidden USB keyfile](http://www.oxygenimpaired.com/debian-lenny-luks-encrypted-root-hidden-usb-keyfile)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to unlock with this script and a key on a usbpen but i can't open having errors about key not find in boot, someone help?

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh

ask_for_password () {
    cryptkey="Unlocking the disk $cryptsource ($crypttarget)\nEnter passphrase: "
    if [ -x /bin/plymouth ] && plymouth --ping; then
        cryptkeyscript="plymouth ask-for-password --prompt"
        cryptkey=$(printf "$cryptkey")
    else
        cryptkeyscript="/lib/cryptsetup/askpass"
    fi
    $cryptkeyscript "$cryptkey"
}

device=$(echo $1 | cut -d: -f1)
filepath=$(echo $1 | cut -d: -f2)

# Ask for password if device doesn't exist
if [ ! -b $device ]; then
    ask_for_password
    exit
fi

mkdir /tmp/auto_unlocker
mount $device /tmp/auto_unlocker

# Again ask for password if device exist but file doesn't exist
if [ ! -e /tmp/auto_unlocker$filepath ]; then
    ask_for_password
else
    cat /tmp/auto_unlocker$filepath
fi

umount /tmp/auto_unlocker
```